# Sql Server Catalog/DB pointer --

Tags: sql, sql-server, connection-string

I have a production server and I standardized the names of all the DBs on the server to

```
projectName.whatever
```

The problem is I have one database named

```
projectName_logging
```

I want to rename it to

```
projectName.Logging
```

(OCD a bit?)

The problem is there are connection strings that all say projectName_logging. Is there a way to say if a connection is projectName_logging to automatically redirect it to a catalog now named projectName.logging ?

Comment: OCD just a tad bit :)...but i'm the same way.

Comment: Please don't use periods in SQL table, column, view/etc names - nor brackets and other special characters.  This requires using double quotes in ANSI syntax, and hard brackets in SQL Server...

Comment: Point taken about the naming. That aside, is there any way to do what I want to do?

Comment: Sounds like what you really want is a synonym for a database name, which doesn't exist, but you can vote for the feature here: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/288421/allow-create-synonym-for-database

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli - Thanks, you should post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested by the OP, I'm making my comment an answer.

Sounds like what you really want is a synonym for a database name, which doesn't exist, but you can vote for the feature [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/288421/allow-create-synonym-for-database).